# no acceptable operator c++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have the following error i've used lambda and it gives me this error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2678   binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const ENROLL_PERSONAL_LINK_TO_CLIENT'

```
    sort(arrLinkToClients.begin(), arrLinkToClients.end(), [](const ENROLL_PERSONAL_LINK_TO_CLIENT & lhs, const ENROLL_PERSONAL_LINK_TO_CLIENT & rhs)
    {
        return lhs.nTypeOfLink < rhs.nTypeOfLink;
    });

    auto it = unique(arrLinkToClients.begin(), arrLinkToClients.end(), [](const ENROLL_PERSONAL_LINK_TO_CLIENT & lhs, const  ENROLL_PERSONAL_LINK_TO_CLIENT & rhs)
    {
        return lhs.nTypeOfLink == rhs.nTypeOfLink;
    });
```

The vector is vector from obejcts of class ENROLL_PERSONAL_LINK_TO_CLIENT.
any help would be nice !

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice also.

Comment: It looks like the error is elsewhere, since there is no `operator=` used in this code.

Comment: What is the declaration of `arrLinkToClients`? is it `const` where this code is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arrLinkToClients` looks to be `const`. For `sort` to compile it must not be `const`.

Comment: This is `std::sort` complaining that it can't modify through the iterators provided. The `=` is in library code

Comment: @Caleth Yes, I think you are right.

Comment: Yep that was the problem.I was passing it to the method by const and now it's okay. Thanks everyone !